# On ways to solve a special case of 3D heat equation

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations

How would I solve (even if numerically) the heat equation of a 3D box with initial uniform temperature & with a laser hitting the center of the top layer, heating it up at a constant rate? If it is too difficult, you may ignore the box’s boundaries and assume the lazer would make a sine distribution.

Comment: What have you assessed so far?

Comment: Nothing, I am really stuck on this one...

Comment: Can you at least write down the formulation of the equations?